# How can I display total amount, principal and interest earned for a range of years in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I am writing a python program that calculates the compound interest. Right now in my program I ask the user to input the years, day and months and convert it to total years (for example, if user inputs 2 years, 6 months and 73 days, this equals to 2.7 years.) I also understand how compound interest works which is earning interest on interest. In my program, I ask for principal, rate, compounding period and the correct answer returns.
The problem I am having is that I want to be able to display something similar to a table where it displays the total amount, principal and interest earned for a range of years.

I have added what I have so far, I'm still new to python so I appreciate all your help, thank you!

This is what I have so far

````
```
def get_time():
    year = float(input("enter year: "))
    month = float(input("enter months: "))
    day = float(input("enter days: "))
    day = day/365
    month = month/12
    year = (month + day) + year
    print(f"total time in years is: %.2f" %year)
    return year
    
def compound_interest(year):
    p = float(input("enter principal: "))
    r = float(input("enter rate: "))
    n = float(input("enter compounding period: "))
    FV = p * (((1+ ((r/100)/n)) ** (n*year)))
    print ("final amount after" year "years is" FV)
    return FV
    
    year = get_time()
    print(compound_interest(year))
```
````

Comment: Please show the code that you're actually trying to run. The code shown has syntax issues